# Select rows before date in sqlite

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-syncdb

How can I with sql select only those rows where date is before a specific date?

I use sqlite3, I manage my database with Django's `syncdb`, and my date field is created with `date = DateField()`.

Comment: Do you have a `select` query already? Show us what you've tried so far, so that we can better assist you.

Comment: And why you tagged `PostgreSQL`, `SQL-SERVER` and `MYSQL` ?

Answer (score 0):

Select * from yourtable where date < @date_passed_in

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with IF statement
I hope this will help you

```
IF date < @date_passed_in

THEN Your Select Statement
```

Comment: Your date is current date am i right? n @date_passed_in should be in date format like 12-12-2014

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at this [django reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/) for detailed understanding. Search for default types for DateField and also DateTime you will get a fair idea.

For DateField, If no input_formats argument is provided, the default input formats are:

['%Y-%m-%d',      # '2006-10-25' 
'%m/%d/%Y',       # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y']       # '10/25/06'